# Populate dropdown based on another dropdown selected value in laravel - edit form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, dropdown

I found how to accomplish this on another site and I got it working. My issue is though that I need to use it in my edit form (preferably in the same form as my create form, since my create and edit views use the same form). When I go to my edit page, the "Section" dropdown value is selected as it should be. But the "Subsection" is not, because ofcourse I did not click it. Probably it's a fix too easy for me to see, but I am not quite good with javascript. I basically need the second dropdown (the subsection one) to show the correct options based on which "section" (first dropdown) is selected, on my edit view.

Section Model:

```
public function subsections()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subsection');
}
```

Subsection Model:

```
public function section()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Section');
}
```

View:

```
{!! Form::select('section_id', [null=>'-- Select Section --'] + $sections, null, array('id' => 'section')) !!}

<select id="subsection" name="subsection_id" class="select">
    <option>-- First Select Section --</option>
</select>

From my controller: $sections = Section::lists('section', 'id');
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#section').change(function(){
        $.get("{{ url('api/dropdown')}}", 
        { option: $(this).val() }, 
        function(data) {
            $('#subsection').empty(); 
            $.each(data, function(key, element) {
                $('#subsection').append("<option value='" + key +"'>" + element + "</option>");
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('api/dropdown', function(){
    $id = Input::get('option');
    $subsections = Section::find($id)->subsections;
    return $subsections->lists('subsection', 'id');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my controller I added:

```
    $subsections = Subsection::where('section_id', '=', $transaction->section_id)->orderBy('subsection', 'asc')->lists('subsection', 'id');
```

And in my view I did this:

```
    @if(isset($transaction))
    {!! Form::select('subsection_id', [null=>'-- Select Subsection --'] + $subsections, null, array('class' => 'select', 'id' => 'subsection')) !!}
    @else
        <select id="subsection" name="subsection_id" class="select">
            <option>-- First Select Section --</option>
        </select>
    @endif
```

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to select the first option in jquery , you can add :

```
$('#subsection option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
```

Or else if you want to select a particular value, you can do that by

```
$('#subsection option[value="value_to_be_selected"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Use this after you have appended all the values to the subsection

Comment: Sounds good, but the main issue is that the subsection dropdown does not get populated automatically. It does when I select something in the section dropdown, but on my edit page I want the section AND subsection dropdowns to be shown, populated, and the right values selected. So maybe it is a more difficult issue than I expected? :)

Comment: Well, I am assuming you're using different views for edit and create and including the same form, so what you could do is, add an extra script in the edit page to just set the values in the form, which you'd be passing from the controller/route function edit method.

Comment: I had an epiphany. On my form, I just show the subsection dropdown with a query where section = ... and so on. And once I change the section, the subsection dropdown will be changed also. Problem solved. I will post my own answer.

Comment: @BharatGeleda  please your views on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

So, what we will do is initially we will send value to the dependent drop-down as
 `"<option value="">Select Something</option>"` 
and when returning on error create complete drop-down with selected as below value and return, **this will reduce lots of javascript calls.**
**Controller:**

```
if($error){
//create get array of second drop-down, suppose $second_drop
// create complete second drop-down like
$selectbox="";
foreach($second_drop as $option){
            $selectbox.="<option value='". $option->id."'";
            if($request->option2==$ $option->id){
                $selectbox.=" selected ";
            }

            $selectbox.=">".$option->value."</option>";
        }
}
return view('routename', ['selectbox2' =>   $selectbox]);
```

**View:**

```
<select id="subsection" name="subsection_id" class="select">
    {!! $selectbox !!}
</select>
```